# ValueError: cannot encode objects that are that are not 2-tuples

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to upload a file to server and I get this error:

```
ValueError: cannot encode objects that are that are not 2-tuples
```

The code:

```
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
buffer = StringIO()

url = 'http://example.com/files/'
user, password = 'ex', 'ample'

buffer.write(open(r'C:\Users\example\Desktop\code\de.txt','rb').read()) 

r = requests.post(url,  auth=(user, password), files=buffer.getvalue())
```

I tried `auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, pass)` but that didn't work either. What can be the solution?

Answer (score 7):

`files` only accepts a dictionary or sequence of `(key, value)` tuples. Give your file field a name:

```
r = requests.post(url,  auth=(user, password), files={'file': buffer.getvalue()})
```

What name exactly depends on the API you are posting to. This encodes the data to a `multipart/form-data` encoded POST body. See [*POST a Multipart-Encoded file* section](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) of the `requests` quickstart documentation.

If you needed to post the file data *as the sole data in the body*, then use the `data` keyword argument:

```
r = requests.post(url,  auth=(user, password), data=buffer.getvalue()})
```

I'm not sure why you are using a `StringIO` buffer; `requests` can handle a file handle *directly*, without having to read everything into memory up front. Even if you do, you'd pass in the `open(....).read()` result in directly without going through an in-memory buffer first; that's just overkill here.

I'd just open the file and have `requests` read and stream that for us:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\example\Desktop\code\de.txt','rb') as filedata:
    r = requests.post(url,  auth=(user, password), files={'file': filedata})
```

Comment: When I run the script it throws no error the shell only writes out >>> but can't find the file in the server. What can be the problem?

Comment: @Marci: I don't know. We know nothing about the server you are sending this to. What does the server expect? Your question was about the error, which is all I can answer here.

Comment: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 80

Comment: That still doesn't tell me anything about what the server expects.

Comment: I typed this into terminal : scp -P 721 /home/pi/batman.jpg marci@example.com:/ex/amp/le/files them it asks the password and when I enter it, it finally worked !! How can I do that in python? The password-requesting causes a problem in the os.system solution